# How to allow a Sublime Text 3 package for certain file syntax only?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've written a ST3 package (with `.py` plugins, `.sublime-keymap`s and `.sublime-commands` in it) and I want the plugins and the `.sublime*` configuration files to be active **only** for a specific file syntax (e.g. for `.txt` or `.myCustomSyntax`). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the examples provided, you want should use file extensions rather than syntax.  The active syntax can be changed via the syntax menu, whereas file extensions are constant.

```
#■■■■■  Establish Valid File Extensions  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

valid_FileExtensions = []
valid_FileExtensions.append ( "txt" )
valid_FileExtensions.append ( "myCustomFileExtension" )

#■■■■■  Get Current File Extension  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

window        = view.window()
fileExtension = window.extract_variables()[ "file_extension" ]

#■■■■■  Verify Current File Extension  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

file_IsValid = False

for entry in valid_FileExtensions:
    if fileExtension == entry:
        file_IsValid = True

#■■■■■  Exit Routine If File Extension Is Invalid  ■■■■■■■■■■

if file_IsValid == False:
    return
```

Alternatively; if you would prefer to use syntax, you could use:
`fileSyntax = view.settings().get ( "syntax" )`

Optionally; you could create an array of `valid_FileExtensions` at `YourPlugin.sublime-settings`, so that users can dictate which extensions the plugin will work for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a key binding I use for the plugin [Markdown Preview](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Markdown%20Preview)

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "markdown_preview", "args": {"target": "browser"},
    "context": [{ "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown" }]
},
```

As you can see I'm using the key `ctrl+b` that is usually bound to the `build` command, but it's only active when my cursor is in a  "text.html.markdown" which happen only in markdown files.
Therefore `ctrl+b` build as usually when I'm in another type of file.

This scope is usually on the form "text.html ..." or "source.python ...". To find the current name of the scope your cursor is, use the command "show_scope_name" with `ctrl+alt+shift+p`.

[Relevant documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html?highlight=key%20binding#structure-of-a-key-binding)